# Laos visa-on-arrival for Indian Citizens: Is it also available at land border crossings?

Tags: visas-on-arrival, laos

I know via air travel India is one of the countries on the VOA scheme for Laos.

What I am not able to confirm is whether that applies to land crossings as well.

I wanted to see if anyone knew whether there are any restrictions when travelling between Ubon Ratchathani in Thailand to Pakse in Laos. I read some blogs online which suggested some crossings have countries that they do not issue VOA for, but wasn't able to confirm if India was on the list or not.

I understand this is a very specific question and may not be easy to answer, but any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You will be fine, VOA is processed on the Pakse riverbank once you cross from Thailand. Laos Customs will give you a form to fill then decide on the fee based on your nationality.

Answer (score -1):

I am sure that Indian passport holders can enter Thailand only by air and not by road - as of now. They can however exit Thailand by road, there is no restriction on that. But, whether the new country takes them by road is a question that is being discussed here. Cambodia does take Indian passport holders by road - that's sure - visa on arrival is issued but taking one online is preferred. Though my answer is not exactly a response to whether visa is issued to Indian passport holders travelling by road from Thailand to other neighbouring countries, it does safeguard them against some issues that they might face upon their returns. The Indian passport holders MUST NOT travel by road from Laos to Thailand but for Thailand to Laos (vice versa) might be possible. The reverse by road for an Indian passport holders is a no.